# How to use sessions in PDO?

Tags: php, session, authentication, pdo

I am still redoing and getting rid of old mysql_* commands in my code. I tried to transfer my session login form old code and this is what I got so far:

```
  public function login($user, $password)
  {
    if (!empty($user) && !empty($password))
    {    
      $password = $web->doHash($user, $password); // in this function is (return sha1(strtoupper($user).':'.strtoupper($password))
      $stmt = $db_login->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE username=:user AND pass_hash=:password");
      $stmt->bindValue(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->execute();
      $rows = $stmt->rowCount();

      if ($rows > 0)      
      {    
        $results_login = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $results_login['username'];
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $results_login['id'];  
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

After that I am using checks if user logged on site:

```
  public function isLogged()
  {
    return (!empty($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_name']));
  }
```

But it seems - this function returns always empty because $_SESSION does not exists in PDO? And of course logout is used in this form on my sites:

```
  public function logout()
  { 
      unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
      unset($_SESSION['user_name']);       
  }
```

But I think PDO has different way of handling session? I did not find any so what is it can i somehow add $_SESSION in PDO withou changing code much?

I am using variables `$_SESSION['user_name']` and `$_SESSION['user_id']` in all over my web project.

Summary:

1) How to use sessions in PDO correctly?

2) What is difference between using `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and `$stmt->fetchAll();`

Thank you.

Comment: +1 for getting rid of mysql_*. Now to read your question :)

Comment: PDO and Sessions are 2 unrelated features of PHP. They can and usually do, coexist. Does you login function return true and still the session variables are empty? Did you call `session_start()` beforehand?

Comment: I did not called session_start() - where should I put it? I had just __contruct there but i deleted it.

Comment: @Truth Like this: http://paste2.org/p/2049513 so should I put it back or somehow redo it? Also do you know answer to my second question, please? Thank you.

Comment: Can't you see it with your Byakugan? I guess my Rinnegan is stronger... :P Look at my answer.

Comment: I see it now I did not rolled down my Byakugan is powerful! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PDOStatement::rowCount()` does not work mysql, So $rows won't return anything.
Plus, PDO has nothing to do with session, it's an extension to deal with databases.

If you want to count the number of result you can do

```
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
$results = count($results);
```

Comment: And do you know the answer to my second question please? :)

Comment: I know when to use the one or the other but wouldn't be able to explain it clearly. You should read the manual or someone else could explain.

Comment: So here is this case is what better to use? Or maybe safer or more practical? :)

Comment: `fetch()` returns one row (you can use it in a `while` loop to have each rows), and `fetchAll()` returns an array of associative array (with all the rows). So it depends of what you need

Comment: So even when I need to fetch only one I can use fetchAll and do not care if I understand correctly :)

Answer (score 3):

The answers are as follows:

1. Call `session_start()` at the top of every page you are using sessions.
2. The difference is that `$stmt->fetch()` will fetch one row, and `fetchAll()` will fetch the entire resultset.

Comment: And if it works also without session_start() should I still use it? And should I use something like session_destroy() in my logout function?

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

1) Ensure session_start() is called at the start of all pages that use Sessions

2) Ensure that data is being returned from your query

Further information

`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` retrieves the data indexed by column name. i.e. an [associative array](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31840&seqNum=3).

In my opinion it is always better to use the `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` because it is quite clear what data is being fetched & processed.

You can also use this code to fetch all the rows in the associative array format if you choose`fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

For more information regarding the  `FetchAll` PDO function  have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: So it seems It dos not properly add variable to $_SESSION['user_name'] and $_SESSION['user_id'] it finally after edit the function comes there but session variables are empty when I print them any idea? even the print successfuly print inside that function but empty variables ... I am desperate.

Comment: Have you ensured that the if statement is being run - if ($rows > 0) & that session_start() has been called in all the required pages?

Comment: @Byakugan - After checking the 2 items I suggested in my earlier comment, I would also suggest checking the following variables are populated: $results_login['username'] & $results_login['id']